# Looking for piano waltzes similar to this one

Tags: identify-this-genre, similar-artists

I'm pretty sure this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2qban_wWOg&t=15m is a modern piano waltz composed specifically for this anime (I couldn't find its name in the OST though, but I can't read Japanese. I listened to all available Youtube OST tracks and none of them was this waltz).

**Question**: can you think of a similar piano waltz composed by a famous composer? Or can you tell me where can I find a similar piano waltz or style?

#### Background for the question

I can't think of a famous composer who played something similar. Classic waltzes are kind of solemn; Russian waltzes are more mournful (beautifully so), Austrian waltzes are more pompous and energetic, I can think of none that is so light, playful and joyful as this one. It speeds up quite often and has a jazzy quality to it (not only the sustain, but the stress points in the rythm), so I doubt a pre-20th century waltz would be like this one.

I'd really appreciate if someone could put me on the right track. I'm looking foward to composing something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Reminded me of this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7yxoncSym-s by Tchaikovsky.